# Как привязать событие нажатие клавиши на кнопку submit? JS

Tags: javascript

Дабы ускорить процесс работы на сайте, очень бы помогла данная функция.
Требуется несколько клавиш привязать к кнопкам. Проще говоря нажимаю "G" он кликает на input type="submit" value="next".

Comment: Повесьте на документ слушателя события поднятия клавиши.

Answer (score 0):

Коды клавиш можете с юзать от сюда [http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Коды_символов_и_клавиш](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B8_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88)

```js
// Вариант на jQuery
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) console.log('Enter');
  if(e.which == 65) console.log('A');
  if(e.which == 66) console.log('B');
  if(e.which == 67) console.log('C');
  if(e.which == 68) console.log('D');
});

// Вариант на ванильном JS
document.onkeyup = function checkKeycode(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) console.log('Enter');
  if(e.which == 65) console.log('A');
  if(e.which == 66) console.log('B');
  if(e.which == 67) console.log('C');
  if(e.which == 68) console.log('D');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```